# Automating API Tests in Tosca

Tags: tosca

Is there a way or how can we test API redirects or chain links in Tosca? How can we capture the next API in the chain?

Calling the main or start API to trigger link is successful but can't retrieve the result or see the runtime result of the succeeding APIs...